# Java Using proxy settings in jar

Tags: java, proxy

I'm doing a webscraping with jar i created, which uses a proxy.
My question is that i have large project where more webscrapers will work in paralel.

Using this code:

```
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "someProxyURL");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", "someProxyPort");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyUser", "someUserName");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPassword", "somePassword");
```

will affect the others webscrapers?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run them as separate processes, then each process has its own system properties. If you are running them in one process as separate threads, they share those properties.

Comment: one question, i'm using threads for each webscrapper, this means my proxy settings will affect just the one with proxy settings?

Comment: No, all the webscrappers in the one process will use the same settings if they get configuration from the system properties even if they are different threads.